# How do I host an API in the Java Play Framework?

Tags: java, api, playframework, intellij-idea, hosting

I am currently working on an API with Play framework.

I have the files open in intellij and it all runs fine in there, but there are obviously multiple files, etc... how do I export them.. what do I export them to, how does my website interact with them.. do I need to run a server?  I have web hosting with a remote company, is it likely I can upload such a file to them and it will host properly, or is this a solve in house kind of an issue.. I am just completely baffled and lost.

Comment: I edited your question, leaving only the parts that pertain to your actual question, and removing the casual conversation.  What's left isn't much of a question. Did you want to know something specific?

Comment: It is a shame you edited out the most important information....
"I am coming to this forum for help because I am just not understanding the actual process of publishing an API, hosting an API, and interacting with an API."

TL/DR: Help me understand the process of hosting APIs.

Comment: That fact is abundantly clear in the remaining text, and I put the tl;dr in the title of your question.  Note that we're not a forum.

Comment: You said there isn't much left of a question... and did I want to know something specific... I wanted to ensure my comment reflected the specifics I wanted answered.  However, I was not aware that my question would be stripped of integrity and edited to a 5 line from a 30 line question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am not understanding the actual process of publishing an API, hosting an API, and interacting with an Api, please help me understand How to implement it... my original explained all of this

Comment: That's a bit broad, isn't it?  I was kinda hoping you could come up with something *specific* to ask.  Don't these things come with manuals?

Comment: Robert, if you read and understood what you read of my original writing, than all of this would be apparent to you, I apologize if it is not, luckily mguillermin was able to understand what I wanted to know and answer in a more pleasant and less derogatory tone.

Comment: His answer was basically RTFM.  I could have just as well said the same thing, as a decent answer to your question would make a good, if rather lengthy, blog post.

Comment: In any case, it appears that there's no way to ask people to be more specific with their questions without appearing derogatory, no matter how polite you try to be.  You might want to read the [faq] before asking your next question.

Comment: Even after reading the pre-edited question I'm not sure what this is all about. If the question is not clear then you cannot expect a clear answer...

Comment: @JohnBishop Here is a guide on how to deploy your Play application to Heroku: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ProductionHeroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a server with a JVM installed. You should probably ask your hosting provider for that.

Once you have the server ready, you will find more information about deploying your application in the "Deploying your application" section from the Play Framework documentation. Read this page : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Production and its related pages.

Comment: Thank you mguillermin for being helpful.